# add text input on certain column table when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm quite new in jquery table . I have a code that will add text input in certain column that I clicked . In my case ,the column is number 9th .Below is my code :

```
$('#PtptnFileTblId_1').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var file_id = $(this).attr('name');
        var code = $(this).text();

        var textrowId = $(this).children("td:nth-child(9)");
        textrowId.html("<input type='text' id='callerid' name='callerid' style='width:100px;' value=''/>");

    } );
```

After click on certain row ,I want its column number 9th will add some text fields that enable me to edit its text but the problem is my code seem not working. Before this I use the same code but different ways and it worked.Please help me with my code above .Any help will greatly appreciate

Comment: Kindly add a snippet ;-)

Comment: you are adding text box  for col = 9  in 1 row or many row ??....if that the case you have to give unique id to text box

Comment: @Vicmathur only one row that I clicked

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler, `$(this)` refers to the cell that was clicked. You can use `closest('TR')` to retrieve the table row:

```
$('#PtptnFileTblId_1').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
    ...
    var cell = $(this).closest('TR').children('td:nth-child(9)');
    cell.html("<input type='text' id='callerid' name='callerid' style='width:100px;' value='' />");
});
```